# CasperJS form submit data even if it is disabled

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, casperjs

I'm using latest casperjs and I have to fill a 'ugly' form but don't submit it. 
To make it work I need to click on a link, not the submit.
I'm using casper 1.1, but it seems to me that form is submitted even if I put false as parameter.

```
casper.start('http://xxxxx/DesktopPortalMain.aspx?menuid=1071', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.fill('form[action="DesktopPortalMain.aspx?menuid=1071"]', {'RootLayout$PageLayout$ContentPane$Frame2204$Module2204$txtSearch': 'FE0140062700' }, false);
    this.click('a#RootLayout_PageLayout_ContentPane_Frame2204_Module2204_btnSearch');
});
```

What is wrong with this? Result of the page are like when the form is submitted without the click on the link.